# run celery and aiohttp in the same service

Tags: python, python-3.x, celery, aiohttp, sockjs

my goal is to send live notifications to the user.
the message will arrive from a `celery` worker.
and will be sent to the user using `aiohttp` through `sockjs`.

how can i run both on the same app ? or receive the messages on the `aiohttp` instance where i have data of the authenticated users in memory ?
what is the best approach to achieve that  ?

i have tried running them together using the `aiohttp` `on_startup`. but celery is blocking the main thread so its not possible.

```
async def run_celery(app):
    .... run celery
app = web.Application(loop=asyncio.get_event_loop())
app.on_startup.append(run_celery)
sockjs.add_endpoint(app, msg_handler, name='messeging', prefix='/sockjs/')
```

thank you very much.
shay

Comment: Keep your Celery workers and aiohttp-based web service separate. It makes no sense to have them all in one big application. Blocking code should be executed in a separate thread so it does not block the main event loop.

Comment: @DejanLekic thank you for the comment. how can i make tasks run on the aiohttp side. where i have the needed data in memory ?

Comment: Your Celery task would be then extremely trivial - an HTTP request to your aiohttp-based service, and return whatever was returned by the web-service.

Comment: thanks again @DejanLekic. if i understand correctly the celery worker should notify aiohttp server using http request ? (the aiohttp need to push data to the client)